# Flutter/Dart: Get URL from Shared Preferences Widget to use in Image.Network Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, static-methods

I need to get an URL from Flutter's Shared Preferences widget and insert it into the Image.network widget. So here's the class I created;

```
class GetSharedPrefs() {
  static getCurrentNameSF() async {
    String currentname;
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    currentname = prefs.getString("currentname");
    print(currentname);
  }
}
```

I tried turning the method into a variable called "spavatar" and inserting it into the build;

```
String spavatar = GetSharedPrefs.getCurrentNameSF().toString();
```

inserted into;

```
 icon: Image.network(
                spavatar,
              ),
```

But it throws the following error:

```
I/flutter (24368): The following _TypeError was thrown attaching to the render tree:
I/flutter (24368): type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

So how do I get the result of the function into the Image.network widget which requires a URL?  Or is there another way I should do this?

Answer (score 2):

This function must resturn a `value` and as it async method, it has to be a `Future<type>`:

```
class GetSharedPrefs {
  static Future<String> getCurrentNameSF() async {
    String currentname;
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    currentname = prefs.getString("currentname");
    print(currentname);
    return currentname;
  }
}
```

Now call:

```
String spavatar = await GetSharedPrefs.getCurrentNameSF();
```

Comment: Android Studio throws up an underlined red on the "await" bit of "String spavatar = await GetSharedPrefs.getCurrentAvatarSF();" Does this need to be wrapped in something?

Comment: await GetSharedPrefs.getCurrentAvatarSF(); is a future function this means it has to be in an async method or use it as unblockable like : GetSharedPrefs.getCurrentAvatarSF().then((spavatar ) { ... TODO ... });

Answer (score 1):

`getCurrentNameSF()` is `async`, so you can't use it in a synchronous method like the `build`.

You might want to keep the SharedPreferences instance as a state. To do that though, you have to initialize it in the `initState` method :

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // anonymous async function
    () async {
      prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    }();
  }
```

Now you can do :

```
Image.network(prefs?.getString("currentname") ?? "alternative")
```

*?? is a null-aware operator. It returns the value on the right side if the left one is null.*

Comment: I like the idea of keeping the SharedPreferences instance as a state. However I'm getting this error:The method 'getString' was called on null.
 Receiver: null
Tried calling: getString("currentname") . I guess I have to make sure the currentname key pair in shared preferences is filled first? Was hoping your ?? option would allow me to specifiy a default URL if shared prefrences didn't exist.

Comment: The "alternative" part is the default URL. But yes I forgot to put a ? after prefs. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

I used both suggestions in the end. First, declare the variable as a placeholder;

```
String currentname = "https://example.com/defaultavatar.png";
```

Then;

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
        () async { prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    currentname = await prefs.getString("currentname"); 
     }();
  }
```

and then;

```
Image.network(
                  currentname ,
                  height: 30,
                  width: 30,
                ),
```